# Convert Array string elements into array

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, indexing

I have an array like this:

```
var sliceDATA = ["7 FIXED BUT FX KFY 200",
                 "9 FIXED BUT FZ MX KFY 150 KMZ 200"];
```

I'd like to convert this into something like this:

```
[[,7,FIXED,BUT,FX,KFY,200], [9,FIXED,BUT,FZ,MX,KFY,150,KMZ,200]];
```

Comment: `I'd like to` Have you made any attempt yet to accomplish what you'd like to achieve? Post the code you've tried, and explain how the output relates to the input

Comment: Long answer short - loop through the array, split using spaces and create an array and push the values finally make a new array and push the individual valued arrays into the new array.

Comment: Why does the first element of your result start with a comma, but the second doesn't?

Comment: Your resultant arrays do not contain strings. FIXED, BUT, etc are not valid elements in the array unless there are actual variables named as those.

Answer (score 8):

What about

```
var result = sliceDATA.map(elm => elm.split(' '));
console.log(result);
```

[Array.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) will apply the anonymous callback function on every element of the array.

The result will be:

```
[
  ["7", "FIXED", "BUT", "FX", "KFY", "200"], 
  ["9", "FIXED", "BUT", "FZ", "MX", "KFY", "150", "KMZ", "200"]
]
```

Comment: That does not return what OP was asking for. (though he hasn't explained the purpose of the leading empty element)

Comment: @CertainPerformance in fact it does, but I miss-copied the output from the consol.

Comment: @CertainPerformance you are right, though it is still not clear if OP made a typo.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
const newArr = sliceDATA.map((currVal) => {
  let newVal = currVal.split(' ');
  return newVal;
});
```

Comment: no need to use an anonymous function and local variable, just return the  split expression immediately.

Comment: Yes, I noticed from your answer above. Thanks

Answer (score -1):

You can use the loop and use split whitespace, it will return an array of elements.

refer to: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp